# CosmosDB output binding error in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm having an issue with Azure Function and CosmosDB output binding. What I have right now: I read from a Cosmos DB container, process something, then output the result back into the same DB but a different container. **I'm using VSCode and python** and I tested other outputs (blob, HTTP response, etc.) and all worked, so I believe it's a CosmosDB issue.

The `__init__.py` main function definition is this:

```
def main(documents: func.DocumentList, outdocs: func.Out[func.Document]):
```

The function.json output binding is this:

```
{
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outdocs",
      "databaseName": "db-test",
      "collectionName": "out-collection",
      "connectionStringSetting": "dmcosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "partitionKey": "undefined",
      "collectionThroughput": "undefined"
}
```

And note that I manually installed the extensions using `func extensions install`, and my extensions.csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <!-- <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion> -->
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It uses the same connection string and database as the trigger input binding, just a different container for output. I also made sure the name of the binding matches the variable I use in the code and its type is `func.Out[func.Document]`. I create a custom dictionary of my output then I use `outdocs.set(func.Document.from_dict(output))` to store the output back into CosmosDB.

Any suggestions? I remember being able to do this a few weeks ago without any issues with the same configuration. The error message I'm getting is this:

```
[2021-08-23T11:30:31.794Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-08-23T11:30:31.891Z] The 'CosmosTrigger' function is in error: Unable to configure binding 'outdocs' of type 'cosmosDB'. This may indicate invalid function.json properties. Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved. I had to delete the last two attributes of my Cosmos output binding and it worked. I was under the impression that because the container already existed, both of these attributes will be ignored.

```
"partitionKey": "undefined",
"collectionThroughput": "undefined"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the update! Really weird that the VSCode extension automatically generates these properties when they do actually prevent the function from running correctly.